# Why did two hours pass before Kirika was asked to put away the pocketwatch?

Tags: noir

In episode 1 of *Noir*, Kirika and Mireille speak at Kirika's home after surviving the attack at the construction site. After some initial discussion of Kirika's circumstances, Mireille prompts her to take out her pocket watch. Kirika complies and opens the face of the watch. This appears to start the melody that troubles Mireille, and the face of the watch reads 19h.<sup>1</sup>

[image: watch face after Kirika takes out watch]

After a shot of Mireille's troubled face, we see that the watch face has shifted to 21h05.

[image]

There is then a short flashback involving Mireille as a child, after which Mireille tells Kirika to put away the pocket watch.

**Why did so much time pass before the pocket watch was removed, if Mireille has such a knee-jerk reaction to it? Is there anything that happens before the removal of the watch that the viewers are not being shown?**

---

1. I considered the possibility that I had confused the minute and hour hands on the watch. However, that does not work with the layout of the clock face: if it were 00h35 and not 19h, the hour hand should be closer to the first tick on the pocket watch.